# How do I prevent PhpStorm from moving cursor to the left when I press Ctrl+S for save file?

Tags: ide, phpstorm

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> for save in PhpStorm, it moves the cursor all the way to the left when it is position for a few tabs/indents forward. I save the file constantly so the cursor constantly moves to the left and I need to re-tab.

How do I prevent the cursor from moving to the left every time I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>?

This only happens when the cursor is on a blank line with only tabs in it.

Comment: this is preventing me from using phpstorm, if someone could help me with this issue I'd probably switch over to phpstorm from my current editor in an instant.

Comment: The issue is resolved and fix will be available in PhpStorm 2016.3.2 (if you are using EAP builds -- next one will have it). In meantime -- see duplicate.

Comment: thanks, go the answer from the other question, works perfectly now